# I can't create different layout for S3 and Nexus4

Tags: android, layout, screen-resolution

I can not create a different layout for these two devices (S3 and Nexus 4).
Creating these folders:

```
-/res/layout-xhdpi
-/res/layout-sw360dp
```

Both devices refer to **"layout-sw360dp."** Maybe I'm wrong settings of AVD?
For S3 I configured like this:

```
Name: Galaxy S3
Screen Size: 4.8
Resolution: 720 x 1280
Size: Large
Screen Ratio: Long
Density: xhdpi
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For Nexus 4  create

```
-res/layout-sw384dp
```

For Samsung S3

```
-res/layout-sw360dp
```

Answer (score 0):

Both these devices are from the same bucket of screen resolution and size. Both are xhdpi and sw360dp. They'd have the same layout. Why do you want to create different layouts for them?

Comment: Because the two devices are not equal.
The resolution in the AVD are set like this:

Nexus 4: 768 x 1280
Galaxy S3: 720 x 1280

So values ​​like: **layout_marginLeft are wrong...**

Comment: Which layout are you using? Use Relative Layout and you won't have to worry about these things? There are more than 4k android devices, you can't write an xml for all the screen sizes. Check the Android documentation on [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html).

Comment: My layout is simply image with a comic bubble and I have to write into this. If the resolution changes, the margin to start writing change...Maybe I need to change approach...

Comment: You should definitely be doing this in a more dynamic way. You shouldn't really be hardcoding any values related to layout.